# wrong string in C# when populate a combobox

Tags: c#

I have this in a class :

```
   public static DataTable CargaCombo(string cmd)
    {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = @"Data Source=GIZEH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sisgar;User ID=sa;Password=giza3587";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        cnn.Open();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter DP = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cnn);
        DP.Fill(DT);
        cnn.Close();
        return DT;
    }
```

later i call this method in a form for populate some combobox:

```
    public DataTable LlenarCombo(string tabla)
    {
        DataTable DSC;
        string CMDC = string.Format("select * from " + tabla + " where ativo=1") ;
        DSC = Utilidades.CargaCombo(CMDC);
        return DSC;
    }
```

all the tables in the database have the column ativo, is posible a concatenation error?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NIKW.png)

Comment: Given the error I can only think that you are not looking at the same database that gives you the error (or you mispelled _ativo_).

Comment: By the way, these "do it all" database methods become, in the long run, more a problem than an assets. For example, a combo usually requires only a ValueMember and a DisplayMember, but you load all the datatable fields. Passing the table as string becomes a security concern (sql injection) and I don't even start talking about how do you think to handle "where" conditions. Please invest some of your time to learn a good ORM tool.